# How can we dynamically add new cell between two given cell in TableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I need to add a new cell on selection of a cell of table. The new cell should come below the selected cell. Can we do it?

Below is the code where I am creating 4 cells and want to insert a cell between 2 and 3.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];


if(indexPath.row == 0){

    cell.textLabel.text = @"My Tweets";
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tweets.png"];
}

if(indexPath.row == 1){

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Search";
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"];
}

if(indexPath.row == 2){

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Followers";
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"followers.png"];
}

if(indexPath.row == 3){

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Following";
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"following.png"];
}



return cell;
```

}

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

//here I have to insert a new cell below on the click this existing cell.


if(indexPath.row == 1)
{

    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:0];
    NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]; 

    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPaths] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

}

Comment: Use `UITableView`s `-beginUpdates`, `-endUpdates` and `-insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

Comment: Hey, I am struggling with the same issue. Did you get any solution.? I know it's been a long time but can you help me

Answer (score 1):

You should update your data source and then call this UITableView method:

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

This is going to call the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method of the table view data source, and update your table, with the animation that you choose.

You would not create the new cell in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method as you are doing in the code that you posted.

---

edited to add info.

To set the indexPaths array (for your case) you can do this:

```
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSInteger section = [indexPath section];    
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row+1 inSection:section];
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
```

Comment: how are IndexPaths and IndexPath related??

Comment: indexPaths is just an array of indexPaths. I'll update my answer with an example that should work in your case.

Comment: getting this error - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: If sounds like you're not updating your data source to add the extra row. What is in your table view data source tableView:numberOfRowsInSection method?

Comment: You didn't add the code for the numberOfRowsInSection method. This is what would probably cause the error that you posted. However the way that you have your code written, you're never going to be able to insert a cell because your cells are hardcoded. Your cell data should probably be in an array in which the index corresponds to each row. You need to update your cellForRowAtIndexPath method to fill in your cells from this array. In your didSelectCellAtIndexPath method you would update this array, and the call the insertRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your question do not do indexpath.row+1 while creating array on indexpath
and then call insertrowatindexpath on tableview.........aloso reload table and you are done.

You can add this method to add rows to your tableview

```
    - (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:
                            [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];
        if (editing)
        {
            [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths
                                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        }
        else {
           //Your Operation [[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:paths
                                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        }
[tableView reloadData];
    }
```

You can use the above method if you have subclassed UITableview else go through the [tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-DeleteandaddrowfromTableView.html)

Also mention on what event you want to insert the rows.Just to insert row you can implement the following logic:-

Create array for paths:-

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```

you have to give the previous row number after which you want to insert the row and the section and then you call the method insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: on the tableview and reload it.

Comment: I think this would not help, as i have to add a new row between. Will try for sure.

Comment: yep !! It only added a new row in the last.

Comment: say you have 8 rows and you have to add after 6th then create indexpath for row 6 and section 0 .also remove the condition  if(indexpath.row==1)from didselectRowAtIndexPath...revert back if solved:)

Comment: Actually did that. Tried using your function just, but the row got added in the last.

Comment: NSInteger section = 0;
   NSInteger row = 5;
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];Did you convert it to NSARRAY???
   NSArray *indexPathsToInsert = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];

   [[self mainTableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

Comment: I dont know if it works for you. But here it is simply adding up a row at last index.

Answer (score 1):

Just call the insertrowsatindexpath delegates within the begin update and end update block.For example try it like this:

```
[tableViewForFinishRace beginUpdates];
        NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath    indexPathForRow:arrayForTitle.count-1 inSection:0];
        NSLog(@"index path for insertion =%@",newIndexPath);
        [tableViewForFinishRace insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [arrayForTitle insertObject:@"Gearing Up for a" atIndex:arrayForTitle.count-1];
        [arrayForImage insertObject:@"gearing-up-icon.jpeg" atIndex:arrayForTitle.count-2];
[tableViewForFinishRace endUpdates];
```